# Regex in c# that could either match new line or ignore it

Tags: c#, regex, line-breaks

Relatively new to Regular expressions in c#. Struggling to get this right.

Requirement:

Input string format : Some random text XXXX caused disturbance of XXXX hours of rework. Due to some random text reported in XXXX

I needed to fetch all the 3 XXXX from the input.

Concrete example: 
Complaint listed in some portal is like below ***RequirementChanges*** caused disturbance of ***200 hours*** of rework. Due to this there is a request reported in ***Excel***.

My regular expression should give the result :
RequirementChanges , 200 hours, Excel.

The additional information about the input string is that :
Only ***caused disturbance***, ***of rework***, ***reported in*** will always be there in the input string. Remaining could be any random text and line breaks could be anywhere in between except these 3 constant strings.
I am planning to parse this input string in c#. Request your inputs. Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\s+` match all kind of vertical and horizontal line breaks. And it's opposite `\S+` would match one or more non-space characters.

```
@"\S+(?=\s+caused disturbance)|\S+\s+\S+(?=\s+of rework)|(?<=\breported in\s+)\S+"
```

**Code:**

```
String input = @"Complaint listed in some portal is like below RequirementChanges caused disturbance of 200 hours of rework. Due to this there is a request reported in Excel.";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\S+(?=\s+caused disturbance)|\S+\s+\S+(?=\s+of rework)|(?<=\breported in\s+)\S+");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/qckHzY)